# Avoid accordion pushing down the row in Grid

Tags: css, grid, toggle, accordion

Is there any solution to avoid accordions in a grid pushing down the entire row, but instead only pushing down the column underneath?
Let's say we have a grid containing 3 columns and 5 rows. Each object in the grid (Card) has an accordion at the very bottom of it.

Comment: You need to provide more details so we can help you, please check the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also check out the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it would be even more helpful if you can provide a working example with the code you've tried so far so also check [Minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.